# Mapped network drive should have IIS installed to search folder from other server?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Is it required that the mapped network drive server should have IIS installed to fetch folder using classic asp?

The code which I written is working fine when I try to check folder exist or not on server1. But when I try to check path exist on server2 or not it is not working. It always gives a message that folder does not exist.

Please note Server2 don't have installed IIS.
I am running code from server1 where IIS is installed.

**Form.asp**

```
    <FORM method="post" encType="multipart/form-data" action="Upload.asp" >
    <INPUT type="File" name="File1">
    <INPUT type="Submit" value="Upload">
    </FORM>
```

**Upload.asp**

```
<%dim fs
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'to check whether folder exist or not
if fs.FolderExists("\\Servre1\temp")=true then
    response.write("Folder  exists!")
else
    response.write("Folder does not exist!")
end if
set fs=nothing%>
```

Above code is working fine if I want to find folder exist or not on same server, but not working for server 2. That's why I am trying with Mapped network drive. It again not working.

Issue is mapped network drive don't have installed IIS, so the code written on server1 can work for server2?

Comment: Checking a file location doesn't require IIS.  What *is* required though is that the user account running your ASP page on server1 has access to the folder on server2.  Have you shared the folder on Server2 ?

Comment: Also I would avoid mapped drives and use [UNC](https://www.lifewire.com/unc-universal-naming-convention-818230) instead.

Comment: You are right! @Dijkgraaf I found the problem , I don't have entered user credentials while fetching folder on another server.                                                                                                  Now code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

i would set up a virtual folder that maps to the network drive. that way, you don't need to change any actual code, you just need to set the virtual directory in place for each web server

Comment: I have tried with virtual folder option also.It also works fine and without mapping network drive also it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Below mentioned code is working fine now!

<%

ServerShare = "\\Server1\TEMP\"
UserName = "domain\username"
Password = "password"

Set NetworkObject = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Z: is the name of network drive which you try to access
NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive "Z:", ServerShare, False, UserName, Password

if fs.FolderExists("\Server1\TEMP\")=true then
   response.write("Folder  exists!")
else

set f=fs.CreateFolder("\Server1\TEMP\temp23")
response.write("Folder does not exist!")
end if
set fs=nothing

Set NetworkObject = Nothing
%>
```